# Why does typeid::name return a random name instead of the exported name?

Tags: c++, typeid

I'm trying to get the name of a function. Let's imagine our function is the following:

```
extern DLLEXPORT void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) my_amazing_function(double arg) { ... }
```

Instead of getting the expected `_Z19my_amazing_functiond`, I get something like `FvdE`.

Why does this happen?

here is my magic code:

```cpp
typeid(&my_amazing_function).name()
```

Comment: `typeid(&my_amazing_function)` gives you the type of a pointer to that function, not the type of the function iteself.  Try `typeid(my_amazing_function).name()`

Comment: @NathanOliver I still get the same "error".

Comment: @Maubg yes it's the typeinfo name for `void(double)`

Comment: @appleapple um... what can I do to show the function name?

Comment: @Maubg There is no standardized way of doing that. You need to specify which compiler you are using for a compiler-specific solution or use a library that wraps the compiler-specifics into a common interface, e.g. boost probably has something for that.

Comment: @Maubg afaict nothing in the standard. maybe there is compiler specific intrinsic

Comment: Ah, I forgot, there is a standard way (in some sense) since C++11 there is the macro `__func__` and since name via C++20 via `std::source_location`, but the name is of course completely implementation defined and I think implementations typically do not return a mangled name.

Comment: @user17732522 that'd need to be put inside the function though.

Comment: @appleapple Yes, I think that is true for most compiler-specific solutions as well, e.g. macros like `__func__`.

Answer (score 4):

`typeid` returns `typeinfo` for the *type*, which is `void(double)` in this case, and has nothing to do with function *name* (mangled or not).

Comment: what can I do to export the function with the name?

Comment: also, I have checked exported symbols in the ".so" and the function name is different.